# Into which artifact does one package intermediate classes?

Tags: java, design

We have modularized our API into some independent components. 
Independent meaning these can be built via Maven and used as dependencies for other projects such as webapps.

Now, to use this API, there needs to be an *intermediate processing class* which does a *translation of the client data model into the callee (component) data model*.

The question is does this handler/processor class belong and need to be packaged along with the client application JAR/WAR or is it part of the component JAR.

What is the convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've typically used a separate module for this. That way it's also versioned alongside the client and the server components.

Comment: Yeah we thought of that, would it be a set of Adapters/Translators sitting in a separate JAR? Not many in the team were in favour, believing it should be in A or B and not a separate C. I'm glad someone else has used this approach.

Comment: Another cryptic clue for this problem domain is "What would OSGi push you towards doing?".